# r plot for polygon graph

Tags: r, polygon

If anyone can tell me how to draw this kind of graph in R? http://pharmrev.aspetjournals.org/content/58/3/621/F9.large.jpg
The souce code or r package is what I want.
my original data is like this:

```
A B 0.1
A C 0.5
A D 0.4
B C 0.2
B D 0.1
C D 0.8
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**Diagram package** is what you want. Here is [link](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/diagram/vignettes/diagram.pdf) for examples (vignettes), look at page 11.

Comment: Thank you. Page 9 Figure 5: Plotweb is almost what I want, my data don`t have direction, which means I don`t need arrow, the line is ok, do you know how to plot line instead of arrow? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Maciej, I think the plotweb function is almost what I want, except the arrow, when I add the arr.type="simple" into it, R warns me that arr.type is not plotweb`s parameter. I turned to use plotmat function, the arrow changed from big arrow to simple arrow, but not disappear. Thanks.